# Trim decimal to two places

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm attempting to do the following sum on my View.cshtml page.

```
{{(apart.FinishedHouses * apart.ChargePerItem) * 1.2 - (apart.FinishedHouses * apart.ChargePerItem).toFixed(2)}}
```

As you can see I'm trying to fix the decimal to two places like so:

```
.toFixed(2)
```

Unfortunately using .toFixed(2) in a sum has no affect.  The result shows many figures after the decimal.

I'm sure there is a very simple answer to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put round bracket to your entire expression and then apply **toFixed(2)** to it , like shown below

```
{{((apart.FinishedHouses * apart.ChargePerItem) * 1.2 - (apart.FinishedHouses * apart.ChargePerItem)).toFixed(2)}}
```

currently your **toFixed(2)** gets applied to only second expression i.e.`(apart.FinishedHouses * apart.ChargePerItem).toFixed(2)`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, been away for awhile.  Works perfectly, thank you Neeraj.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add property (like Total) in apart object and use .toFixed(2) in typescript code?